# Shell - What does this command do?

Tags: regex, shell, command-line, find, executable

Can any body explain to me what this command line do :

```
find "$dir1" -regex ".*\.exe" -type f -exec cp "{}" "$dir2/my_executable.exe" \;
```

And I'd like to know why this command has semi-colon at the end.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might find [explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+%22%24dir1%22+-regex+%22.*%5C.exe%22+-type+f+-exec+cp+%22%7B%7D%22+%22%24dir2%2Fmy_executable.exe%22+%5C%3B) useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is finding all `*.exe` files in a directory named `$dir1`. Then each of those files are copied with the name of `$dir2/my_executable.exe` overwriting it every time. So in the end `$dir2/my_executable.exe` will be same as the last found `.exe` file in `$dir` directory.

1. `-type f` => Find only files
2. `-regex ".*\.exe"` => find files with the name with `.exe` in them
3. `-exec` => execute a command on each of the found files
4. `{}` => represents found file name with path
5. `cp "{}" "$dir2/my_executable.exe"` => copy found file to `$dir2/my_executable.exe`
   and the \; terminates the exec statement

Comment: Please, can you give me more details? such as "-type f -exec " and what abt that "{}" and that "\;" in the end? Thanks again!

Comment: @Farah: Added some explanation, please read more about find command in  `man find`

Comment: @Farah: You should consider accepting one of the answers here.

Answer (score 2):

It looks in `$dir` for files with `.exe` extension and copies them to `$dir2/my_executable.exe`, so that `$dir2/my_executable.exe` will end up being the last file found.

#### Explanation

- `find "$dir1"` looks for files in `$dir1`.
- `-regex ".*\.exe"` having name `XXX.exe`.
- `-type f` being files
- `-exec .... {} \;` performs a command in the files found.
- `cp "{}" "$dir2/my_executable.exe" \;` copies the found files into `"$dir2/my_executable.exe"`. As it is always the same, in `"$dir2/my_executable.exe"` you will end up having the last file found.

Comment: +1. Thank you for the answer which is as good as the one I chose. But I had to choose one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon at the end is part of the syntax for the -exec option in the find command:

> ```
>    -exec command ;
>           Execute command; true if 0 status is returned.  All following arguments to find are taken to be arguments
>           to the command until an argument consisting of `;' is encountered.  The string `{}' is  replaced  by  the
>           current file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in argu‐
>           ments where it is alone, as in some versions of find.  Both of  these  constructions  might  need  to  be
>           escaped (with a `\') or quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell.  See the EXAMPLES section for
>           examples of the use of the -exec option.  The specified command is run once for each matched  file.   The
>           command  is executed in the starting directory.   There are unavoidable security problems surrounding use
>           of the -exec action; you should use the -execdir option instead.
> ```